# Modify @RequestBody object in Controller From Filter

Tags: spring-mvc, filter, controller

I want to modify an object that has already been populated with JacksonMapper and add the IP and Referrer URL to it automatically, but the request is always null because it isn't found in the attributes array.  Am I doing something wrong?

ApiController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/member/follow")
    public @ResponseBody IHttpResponse follow(@RequestBody FollowRequest request) {
        return request.getHttpResponse();
    }
```

ApiRequestWrapper.js

```
public class ApiRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    public ApiRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);

        if(this.getAttribute("request") instanceof IHttpRequest)
        {
            IHttpRequest httpRequest = (IHttpRequest) this.getAttribute("request");

            if(httpRequest != null)
            {
                httpRequest.setIp(request.getRemoteAddr());
                httpRequest.setReferrer(request.getLocalName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>apiFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>apiFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Where is the filter being instantiated?  When you say you can't get the attributes, do you mean on the client side?

Comment: I want to modify @RequestBody FollowRequest request inside the Request Filter, before it goes to the Controller so I can have the IP and Referrer in that object.  The filter is instantiated in the web.xml which I added above.

Comment: You can modify the request body, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932518/how-to-modify-request-body-before-reaching-controller-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object corresponding to the RequestBody is created just before the method is invoked - there is no way to get hold of it in the filter.  You can achieve what you want to do by implementing an Aspect.