# How to modify request body before reaching controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application.
I change the request body of every post request.
Is it possible to modify the request body before the request reaches the controller.
Please include an example.

Comment: take a look at this: https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-interceptors-your

Comment: I think is only allow to set request parameter zombie. In my case modify the request body.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short Answer**
Yes, but not easily.

**Details**
I know of three options to change the body of a request
"before" it arrives at the handler method in the controller;

1. Use AOP to change the request before the method is called.
2. Create an HTTP filter.
3. Create a custom Spring HandlerInterceptor.

Since you are already using spring-boot,
option 3, custom Spring HandlerInterceptor,
seems like the best option for you.

Here is a link to a [Baeldung Article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) covering spring HandlerInterceptors.

The Baeldung article is not the full answer for your problem
because you can only read the `InputStrem` returned by `HttpServletRequest` one time.

You will need to create a wrapper class that extends `HttpServletRequest`
and wrap every request in your wrapper class within your custom HandlerInterceptor or in a custom Filter (Filter might be the way to go here).

***Wrapper Class***

1. Read the `HttpServletRequest` InputStream in the wrapper class constructor
2. Modify the body per your requirements.
3. Write the modified body to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.
4. Use `toByteArray` to retrieve the actual `byte[]` from the stream.
5. Close the ByteArrayOutputStream (try-with-resources is good for this).
6. Override the `getInputStream` method.
7. Wrap the `byte[]` in a ByteArrayInputStream every time the `getInputStream` is called.  Return this stream.

**How To Wrap the Request**

1. In your Filter, instantiate your wrapper class and pass in the original request (which is a parameter to the doFilter method).
2. Pass the wrapper to the chain.doFilter method (not the original request).

Comment: Thanks [DwB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453005/dwb) i will work and update the status

Comment: Hi [DwB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453005/dwb) its throws Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed . How can i solve this problem.

Comment: You can only read from the http message stream one time, ever.  that is why you need to wrap the "real" http request in your custom http request wrapper.

Comment: It seems like HttpServletResponse is immutable. i did modiefied body . how to return stream??  since method " preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) " returns boolean.. I even tried by assigning custom HttpServletRequest to  original HttpServletRequest. but it does not work.

Comment: @RujalShrestha Try to pay attention.  This entire answer can be summarized as "wrap the response class in your own class".

Comment: @DWB yeah i did the same.  do we have any way to reinitialize Spring HttpServletRequest

Comment: No.  The HttpServletRequest is, as you noted, immutable.  All you can do is wrap the request and wrap the response.

Comment: have anyone found any solution on this? I tried to implement the same but it's not working. Seeing same error.

Comment: @DwB how do you plan on propagating your wrapped httpServletRequest?  The HandlerInterceptor##preHandle just returns a boolean. You can't wrap then propagate your wrapped object further down the dispatch chain. I think Filters might be a better solution if you plan on wrapping the request object since they have the chain.doFilter(request, response); You can pass your wrapped request/responses around this way.

Comment: Wrap the HttpServletRequest in a Filter.

Comment: 2. Modify the body per your requirements. But how to modify the body? I'm am not able to set the InputStream back to the request.

Comment: @DwB Hi, actually the way I did is to set the value in controller in a method which is handling the post mapping. I just want to know if it's a recommended way to do like this ? Like changing the incoming request in controller ? I have asked the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495940/intercepting-incoming-client-request-using-clienthttprequestinterceptor-with-res

Comment: @DwB Should I override the addInterceptors method inside the custom Logger class in the example? Because it doesn't specify.

Comment: I don't recognize the reference "custom Logger class" in the context of this question.  what do you mean?

Answer (score 16):

Another alternative would be adding an attribute to the **HttpServletRequest** object. And after that you can read that attribute in the Controller class with **@RequestAttribute** annotation.

In the Interceptor

```
@Component
    public class SimpleInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            String parameter = request.getParameter("parameter");
            if (parameter == "somevalue") {
                request.setAttribute("customAttribute", "value");
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

In the Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class SampleController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String work(@RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest, @RequestAttribute("customAttribute") String customAttribute) {
        System.out.println(customAttribute);
        return "This works";
    }
}
```

This has advantage of not modifying the request body.

Comment: don't you need specify `SimpleInterceptor` in `SampleController`? what if you define multiple Interceptors?

Answer (score 10):

My answer using **HTTP Filter**.

**RequestFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        RequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new RequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

**RequestWrapper.java**

```
 public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        private final String body;
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
        public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
            // So that other request method behave just like before
            super(request);
    
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                        stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
    
                } else {
                    stringBuilder.append("");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            } finally {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    try {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Store request body content in 'requestBody' variable
            String requestBody = stringBuilder.toString();
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(requestBody);
            //TODO -- Update your request body here 
            //Sample
            ((ObjectNode) jsonNode).remove("key");
            // Finally store updated request body content in 'body' variable
            body = jsonNode.toString();
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
            ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
                public int read() throws IOException {
                    return byteArrayInputStream.read();
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean isFinished() {
                    return false;
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean isReady() {
                    return false;
                }
    
                @Override
                public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
    
                }
            };
            return servletInputStream;
        }
    
        @Override
        public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I achieved it using the RequestBodyAdvice:

1. Create a class that implements RequestBodyAdvice and annotate it with @ControllerAdvice

```js
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRequestBodyAdvice implements RequestBodyAdvice {
```

2. You will have to implements 4 methods:

a. support: here, you can control which controller you are targeting, and better which request body by specifying the type of the request body

```js
@Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        log.info("In supports() method of {}", getClass().getSimpleName());
        return methodParameter.getContainingClass() == AuthorController.class && type.getTypeName() == AuthorDTO.class.getTypeName();
    }
```

b. beforeBodyReady

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

@Override
public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) throws IOException {
    log.info("In beforeBodyRead() method of {}", getClass().getSimpleName());
    return httpInputMessage;
}
```

c. afterBodyRead: here it is where you can modify the request body

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

@Override
public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
    log.info("In afterBodyRead() method of {}", getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (body instanceof AuthorDTO) {
        AuthorDTO authorDTO = (AuthorDTO) body;
        authorDTO.setName("Test");
        return authorDTO;
    }

    return body;
}
```

d. handleEmptyBody

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

@Override
public Object handleEmptyBody(Object body, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
    log.info("In handleEmptyBody() method of {}", getClass().getSimpleName());
    return body;
}
```

Source: http://www.javabyexamples.com/quick-guide-to-requestbodyadvice-in-spring-mvc

Comment: `type.getTypeName() == AuthorDTO.class.getTypeName()` is this correct? I think you should be using `String#equals`.

Comment: @PEdroArthur both are correct..the goal here is to target the request body type you wish.

Comment: I got that, but my concern is about using `==` to test strings.

Comment: would suggest removing "        return methodParameter.getContainingClass() == AuthorController.class && type.getTypeName() == AuthorDTO.class.getTypeName();". That is actually a 'compileTime test', not a test you would want run with EVERY REQUEST.

Comment: How to handle request that donot have @requestBody annoation

Comment: How can I modify the body in `beforeBodyRead` ? There are several issues.

Answer (score 2):

One way to this is by reflection. ProceedingJoinPoint contains the args object passed to method

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AopInterceptor {

    @Around(value = "@annotation(xyz.rpolnx.spring.web.poc.annotation.AopIntercepExample)")
    public Object handler(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        Class<?> someClass = args[0].getClass();

        Field field = someClass.getDeclaredField("custom");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(args[0], "custom");
        field.setAccessible(false);

        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}

@RestController
public class SimpleController {

    @PostMapping("/aop")
    @AopIntercepExample
    public Person handleAopIntercept(@RequestBody Person nodes) {
        return nodes;
    }
}

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AopIntercepExample {
}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String custom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this this issue too. This thread helped me a bit and I wanted to post a simpler solution than Bijaya Bhaskar Swain.

```
package com.thebois.inpassering.adapters.merchant.staffrestrepo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.thebois.inpassering.adapters.merchant.FilterOrders;
import com.thebois.inpassering.adapters.merchant.facilityownerrestrepo.FacilityOwner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ReadListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;


@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Order(value = FilterOrders.STAFF_REQUEST_ORDER)
public class StaffCreationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter  {

  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestWrapper modifiedRequest = new RequestWrapper(request);
    filterChain.doFilter(modifiedRequest, response);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return !(request.getServletPath().contains("/staff") && request.getMethod().equals("POST"));
  }

  private class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    String body;

    public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
      super(request);
      String body = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request).getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
      //get your dto
      Staff staff = objectMapper.readValue(body, Staff.class);

      //edit your dto
      long facilityOwnerId = ((Number) request.getAttribute("facilityOwnerId")).longValue();
      FacilityOwner facilityOwner = FacilityOwner.builder()
          .facilityOwnerId(facilityOwnerId)
          .build();

      Staff modifiedStaff = Staff.builder()
          .facilityOwner(facilityOwner)
          .username(staff.getUsername())
          .password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(staff.getPassword()))
          .build();

      //save your changes to body
      this.body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(modifiedStaff);
    }


    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
      final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
        public int read() {
          return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
          return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
          return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {

        }
      };
      return servletInputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
      return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }
  }
}
```